# What does a horizontal bar over two vectors indicate?

Tags: notation, vectors, physics

I'm reading a physics paper dealing with angular mechanics. There is a vector ***G*** representing Force of gravity multiplied by a position vector ***C***, all cross-producted with a Force vector. However, there is a horizontal bar (Vinculum?) over the vectors ***G******C***, as shown in the picture:
[Angular Moment of Momentum Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0C2b.jpg).
What does the bar represent? The only thing I could find elsewhere is that it is the complex conjugate, which makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Perhaps [bivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector)?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My Physics teacher said it was the line formed between the two vectors. I am not sure what a non-geometric interpretation of it would be, but the solution was much simpler than I thought.